# I'm trying to print an array using a loop in Javascript in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to print out each array item from a property in an object:

```
{
        position:"Finance Office Assistant",
        employer:"Washtenaw County Finance Department",
        location:"Ann Arbor, MI",
        start_date:"2012",
        current: false,
        end_date:"2012",
        duties: [
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3" 
        ]
    },
```

This object is in an array, with several other objects. I'm trying to create a function that loops through all of the objects and prints out the **duties** array items in an unordered list with the exact number of list items and array items.

Here is the function I'm trying to write to do the task

```
$scope.dutyList = function() {
    var arrayLength = $scope.duties.length;
    while (arrayLength > 0) {
        console.log("dutyList run")
        document.write("<li> {{ dutyList }} </li>");
        --arrayLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: What result are you seeing from your code as it stands, and how is it unlike what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a function to handle displaying data like this.  Angular's ngRepeat is for this.  To access the second level of of your data set you can nest two repeats in your unordered list.  The first one (in a div) repeats the first layer of your data, and exposes the second layer, which repeat in the `<li>` tag:

```
  <ul>
      <div ng-repeat="d in data">
        <li ng-repeat="duty in d.duties">{{duty}}</li>  
      </div> 
  </ul>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/84uYIU4aNN1H704t7DOJ)

Comment: Tried nesting it before, had the syntax wrong. This works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you don't want to write directly to the document when using a framework like Angular. Instead, you should use the built in templating system and directives to render your page.

I'm making some assumptions about the end goal here, but, assuming the array of objects can be accessed by the controller and attached to the scope, you could print your unordered list of duties for each position using something like the following.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.foo = [{
        position:"Finance Office Assistant",
        employer:"Washtenaw County Finance Department",
        location:"Ann Arbor, MI",
        start_date:"2012",
        current: false,
        end_date:"2012",
        duties: [
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3" 
        ]
    }, {
        position:"Another Position",
        employer:"Another Employer",
        location:"Ann Arbor, MI",
        start_date:"2012",
        current: false,
        end_date:"2012",
        duties: [
            "2nd Object, Item 1",
            "2nd Object, Item 2",
            "2nd Object, Item 3" 
        ]
    }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
  <div ng-repeat='bar in foo'>
    <h1>{{ bar.position }}</h1>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat='duty in bar.duties'>
        {{ duty }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will only work if you have display duties from one object.

Comment: @tpie You're correct - I missed that detail in the question. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, I'm just getting into angular and I'm definitely thinking too hard!